# How do I disable Autofac's "lazy resolution"?

Tags: autofac

I have registered this with Autofac:

```
builder.Register(c => ViewerFactory.CreateDefault()).SingleInstance();
```

I'm not sure, but I think that Autofac only calls "ViewerFactory.CreateDefault()" the first time a call to resolve this service is made. Am I correct?

If I am, how can I prevent the "lazy resolution" from happening, only for this service? This will make the UI more responsive the first time this service is required, albeit at the cost of a slight increase in start-up time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use

```
builder.RegisterInstance(ViewerFactory.CreateDefault());
```

That will create the instance immediately and register it, rather than creating it on first use.